# CSS to always display last icon of list cropped to half

Tags: html, css, icons, crop

I have a list of icons and I would like to display the last one always cropped (at about half of its size) so the user knows there are more of them. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1cy7kof8/91/

```
.icons 
{
  background: yellow;
  width: 900px; 
  height: 76px;
}

.icons img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 4px 12px;
}
```

works fine when the size of the output window is 526px then 5 and a half icons are displayed, but when I resize the window to for example 580px then 6 complete icons are displayed and the user has no idea, there are more of them. In this case, I would need to set the margin to "4px 9px" or "4px 16px" to display half of the last icon again.

The only solution I came so far is to use a lot of media queries to adjust these margins, but I have a feeling there should be a better way. :-)

I do not mind adding more divs if needed, but it has to work without any JavaScript.

Any idea?

Comment: It would probably help if there was a modulo operator in css calc(), but as far as I know there is not...

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this...? you can add media queries to icon-wrapper as needed. So that only the icon you wish to show are visible.

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  width: 520px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
.icon-wrapper:hover {
  width: 800px;
}

.icons {
  background: yellow;
  width: 800px;
  height: 76px;
}

.icons img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 4px 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <div class="icon-wrapper">

    <div class="icons">

      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/visualstudio.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/visualstudiocode.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/cplusplus.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/fortran.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/visualstudio.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/visualstudiocode.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/cplusplus.svg" />
      <img height="64" width="64" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@v4/icons/fortran.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: I want all icons to be displayed. User can scroll to right to see more of them, but I would like to a display the last one, which is yet visible as cropped as hint that there is more a spread the spaces between the rest.

Yes this could be accomplished with media queries, but I would need a lot of them...